# Google Analytics: Why are goals completions not showing in conversion

Tags: google-analytics

I just set up Google Tag Manager to fire events when pressing add to cart button. The events are fired correctly using Preview.

Then in Google Analytics, i set up a Goal with Event's label equal to "Add To Cart" (which is the same label i used when creating the Tag in Google Tag Manager).

I can see the goal being recorded if i'm in Real-Time/Conversions

But when i'm in Conversions/Goals/Overview i'm not seeing anything, even though i already set the date range correctly. Is there anything wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics isn't intended to be a real-time tracker, and Goals is one report that does show a delay in reporting. Give it 24 hours (it'll probably show results before that, but 24 hours is recommended to see accurate reports.)

Comment: I just checked today and it indeed needed some delay time to show up. Thanks for that.